# Airflow reference dag name in a python variable

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag like below.

```py
twomins = DAG(
    'upsert_every_2mins',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Every 2mins',
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    doc_md = docs
)
```

Then I tried to reference this DAG name via python variable.

```
dagname = twomins
```

And my task will look like below.

```py
max_ts = PythonOperator(
        task_id="get_maxts",
        python_callable=get_max_ts,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dagname 
    )
```

But its giving error like this.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upsert_every_2and10mins.py", line 148, in <module>
    dag=sync_interval
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 72, in wrapper
    dag_args = copy(dag.default_args) or {}
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'default_args'
```

Am I missing something here?

The reason why I'm using this is, some ETL pipeline will decide which schedule should pickup. If the config has 2mins, then the dag `twomins` will be used for that task.

Comment: You probably should be using a PythonBranchOperator for conditional checks when deciding which task to perform. And I don't think that is the cause of your error - the traceback is pointing to something else it seems.

Comment: But in my case, the dagname might have a different values, lets day `dagname=10mins` then the task will pick the `tenmins` as the dag, (One single python file with multiple dags)

Comment: I don't think airflow works that way with one Python file with multiple DAGs. Each file should be a DAG definition file (singular). See answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a crucial point in how Airflow and DAGs work. The file you have is simply a DAG configuration file, it doesn't actually carry out the code in a sense. So I don't think you can make such a conditional check to decide between DAGs within the file.

From the [tutorial](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html#it-s-a-dag-definition-file):

> One thing to wrap your head around (it may not be very intuitive for everyone at first) is that this Airflow Python script is really just a configuration file specifying the DAG’s structure as code.

And,

> People sometimes think of the DAG definition file as a place where they can do some actual data processing - that is not the case at all! The script’s purpose is to define a DAG object.

If the check is dependent on interval, then why not change the `schedule_interval`?

Comment: Yes, the problem I have is schedule interval, but I think I can't use a single dag with multiple schedule_interval for each task.